# Lambda expression Func with more than 16 params

Tags: linq-to-sql, lambda, linq-expressions

I have to write a filtering lambda expression used in LinqToSQL, which requires more than the number of parameters provided by the standard System.Func (in this case the max number is 16).

```
Expression<Func<BusinessDTO,
                                string,
                                int,
                                int,
                                int,
                                DateTime,
                                DateTime,
                                DateTime,
                                DateTime,
                                DateTime,
                                DateTime,
                                DateTime,
                                DateTime,
                                int,
                                int,
                                int,
                                int,//-> Max number exceeded 
                                bool>> fnFilter = (business,
                                                        Name,
                                                        Redeemed,
                                                        Permanent,
                                                        ApprovedByUser,
                                                        BeginApprovalDate,
                                                        EndApprovalDate,
                                                        BeginExpiryDate,
                                                        EndExpiryDate,
                                                        BeginEntryDate,
                                                        EndEntryDate,
                                                        BeginChangeDate,
                                                        EndChangeDate,
                                                        WorkFlowCode,
                                                        CreatedByUser,
                                                        UpdatedByUser) => ...
```

How can I achieve this?

Here is the usage:

```
filterExpression = Expression.Invoke(fnFilter, businessParam,
                                   Expression.Constant(name),
                                   Expression.Constant(redeemed),
                                   Expression.Constant(permanent),
                                   Expression.Constant(approvedByUser),
                                   Expression.Constant(filter.BeginApprovalDate),
                                   Expression.Constant(filter.EndApprovalDate),
                                   Expression.Constant(filter.BeginExpiryDate),
                                   Expression.Constant(filter.EndExpiryDate),
                                   Expression.Constant(filter.BeginEntryDate),
                                   Expression.Constant(filter.EndEntryDate),
                                   Expression.Constant(filter.BeginChangeDate),
                                   Expression.Constant(filter.EndChangeDate),
                                   Expression.Constant(workflowCode),
                                   Expression.Constant(createdByUser),
                                   Expression.Constant(updatedByUser));

var resultExpression = Expression.Equal(filterExpression, Expression.Constant(true));
            var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<BusinessDTO, bool>>(resultExpression, businessParam);

repository.FindAll(predicate);
```

Comment: Just curious since I have never seen this pattern before. Why can't you compose the predicate from smaller parts.

Answer (score 2):

Our product ran into this limitation back in the .NET 3.5 days, when the limit was 4. We ended up grouping the extra parameters in a single object, for which we created a monstrous generic type with 32 type parameters:

```
class FilterParams<T1,T2,T3,T4,/*..*/,T32> {
    public T1 t1Val {get;set;}
    public T2 t1Val {get;set;}
    public T3 t1Val {get;set;}
    // ...
}

Expression<Func<BusinessDTO,FilterParams<
                    string,
                    int,
                    int,
                    int,
                    DateTime,
                    DateTime,
                    DateTime,
                    DateTime,
                    DateTime,
                    DateTime,
                    DateTime,
                    DateTime,
                    int,
                    int,
                    int,
                    int,//-> Max number is not exceeded :)
                    bool,object,object,/* pad to 32 ...*/>> fnFilter = (business,
                         filterParams) => business.Name.Equals(filterParams.t0val) && ...

var fp = new FilterParams</*ugly type parameter list*/>(
    t0val = name,
    t1val = redeemed,
    t2val = permanent,
    // ...and so on
);

filterExpression = Expression.Invoke(fnFilter, businessParam, Expression.Constant(fp));

// ...the rest is the same as in your post
```

This worked quite well for us. Eventually we extended it to 64, and created 64 different classes to avoid padding type parameters with `object`, like is shown above. Of course we wrote a little script to generate these 64 generic classes.

Comment: It doesn't work since this is going to be converted to SQL calls. The exception is: Could not format node 'Value' for execution as SQL.

Comment: @MichaelH. I see... We never ran into it because we compiled the resultant lambdas for evaluation in memory. There may be an alternative approach, though. Is the structure of your `BusinessDTO` class in any way similar to the parameter list that you are passing? If it is, you may get better luck using it instead of an instance of a generic class.